# Adding user privilege to execute commands do not work

Tags: linux, debian

I want to add a user that is able to execute *"add user"* and *"change password"* commands. I added into visudo a configuration that I found in some Stack Exchange answer, but it does not work.

This is my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias USER_COMMANDS = /usr/sbin/adduser, /usr/sbin/chpasswd

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
sano    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: USER_COMMANDS

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Does anyone know why this is? It asks me for a password anyway or I get:

> adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are no relevant configurations happening in `/etc/sudoers.d/*`, it is safe to assume that the  user *sano* is also in the group *sudo*. This later line overrides the first and thusly the NOPASSWD tag.

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

So the user sano has to enter the passwd for every command.

Cf. this tip from the [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo#Example_entries):

> **Note:** The most customized option should go at the end of the file,
>   as the later lines overrides the previous ones. In particular such
>   a line should be after the `%wheel` line if your user is in this group.